# jquery ajax json .each

Tags: jquery, json

More than I want to admit I've rummaged these sites looking for my error. I cannot find it, them! I'm almost sure no data is being returned from url stoverup.php because I cannot alert the returned data file in the calling stover.htm. I've added the suggested statements, header and parseJSON, to stover.htm, made no difference, not sure they are needed. I've formatted myself the return data in the stoverup file and encoded it which only added \ to the ". Either way it didn't work, with or w/o ! I think the formatting is correct, I followed examples found in stackoverflow and my dumps. Here are the two files, stover and stoverup.

STOVER.HTM

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$.getJSON("stoverup.php", function(data) {
    var ob = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(ob);
});
```

STOVER.PHP

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $dat .= '{"id":"' . $row['marycomid'] . '","com":"' . $row['marycom'] . '"},';
}
$dat=substr($dat,0,strlen($dat)-1); // removes last comma

$co='{"comments":['; //echo $co; beginning of dcon
//$dat = {"id":"hope","com":"a message of hope and charity"},{"id":"mwork","com":"trying something that might work"},{"id":"trial","com":"this is another trail"}"
$coend=']}'; //echo $coend; ending of dcon
$dcon=$co . $dat . $coend;

echo json_encode($dcon);  //for return or dumping
//dumping encoding {\"comments\":[{\"id\":\"hope\",\"com\":\"a message of hope and charity\"},{\"id\":\"mwork\",\"com\":\"trying something that might work\"},{\"id\":\"trail\",\"com\":\"this is another trial\"}]}"
```

Any help will be a mighty relief!

Comment: Have you tried using a combination of Firebug, a Javascript Lint such as http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php, and your PHP error log to try and pinpoint the error?

Comment: `json_encode` takes a PHP object/array and you are passing it a string. Why?

Comment: Tip: Do *not* build your own JSON, like you are doing here!  Just don't.  Create an array that holds the data in the format you want, then `json_encode()` that.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments to your question state, don't build your own JSON string. Building the JSON is what json_encode is for. Instead, try encoding the data like this:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    $data[] = array('id' => $row['marycomid'], 'com' => $row['marycom']);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```